# Definite integral - how to integrate

Tags: definite-integrals

[image]
How to evaluate the first integral with respect to $dx$. If I take $x = a sin\theta$ how will the limits change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

use the substitution

$1-x^2=t \qquad -2xdx=dt$

the new limits are easy to find ...